# Converting Dollars to Cents and Cents to Dollars

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading, forward-declaration

**OBJECTIVE:**

The objective of this code is to convert Dollars to Cents and Cents to Dollars (Vice Versa).

**PROBLEM:**

The problem with this code is that conversion from Dollars to Cents and vice versa only goes one-way. If you remove the line, `operator Dollars() const {return Dollars(m_cents / 100);}`, the code works perfectly fine but in one-way.

Forward declaration of Class does not work and returns C2027 "Use of undefined type 'Dollars'".
Why doesn't forward declaration of class work in this case? It seems to be a circular dependency issue.

**SOLUTION:**

What should one do to solve this issue?

```
#include <iostream>

class Cents;//forward declare Cents for Dollar conversion
class Dollars;

class Cents
{
private:
    int m_cents;
public:
    Cents(int cents = 0)
        : m_cents{ cents }
    {
    }

    // Overloaded int cast
    operator int() const { return m_cents; }

    //int getCents() const { return m_cents; }
    //void setCents(int cents) { m_cents = cents; }

    //Convert Cents into Dollars. C2027 error.
    operator Dollars() const 
    { 
        return Dollars(m_cents / 100); 
    }//myown
};

class Dollars
{
private:
    int m_dollars;
public:
    Dollars(int dollars = 0)
        : m_dollars{ dollars }
    {
    }

    // Overloaded int cast
    operator int() const
    {
        return m_dollars;
    }//myown

    //int getDollars() const { return m_dollars; }//myown
    //void setDollars(int dollars) { m_dollars = dollars; }//myown

    // Allow us to convert Dollars into Cents
    operator Cents() const
    {
        return Cents(m_dollars / 100);
    } //This won't work because it hasn't seen class Cents

};

void printCents(Cents cents)
{
    std::cout << cents << " cents"; // cents will be implicitly cast to an int here
}

void printDollars(Dollars dollars)
{
    std::cout << dollars << " dollars";//myown
}


int main()
{
    //Dollars dollars{ 9 };
    //printCents(dollars); // dollars will be implicitly cast to a Cents here. You get 900 cents
    
    Cents cents{ 2000 };//myown
    printDollars(cents);//myown

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't create a `Dollar` object unless you have the full class definition. Break out the functions and implement them outside the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue may be fixed by moving the implementation to the cpp file. This way you can include the required headers without circular dependencies :

In Dollars.hpp

```
operator Cents() const;
```

In Cents.hpp

```
operator Dollars() const;
```

In Dollars.cpp

```
#include Cents.hpp
Dollars::operator Cents() const
    {
        return Cents(m_dollars / 100);
    }
```

In Cents.cpp

```
#include Dollars.hpp
Cents::operator Dollars() const 
    { 
        return Dollars(m_cents / 100); 
    }
```

---

EDIT :

If you want to keep everything in a single file as in your example, just replace the current definitions by declarations :

```
operator Cents() const;
operator Dollars() const;
```

And move the implementations outside the classes, for instance above the main() function :

```
Dollars::operator Cents() const
{
    return Cents(m_dollars / 100);
}

Cents::operator Dollars() const 
{ 
    return Dollars(m_cents / 100); 
}

int main() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Hi dspr, it doesn't seem to work. I've attached what I did in the main thread.

Comment: I don't see what you have changed, sorry. But have a look at my edit, I show how to fix it if working with a single file as in your example : I tested it and it works.

Comment: operator Cents() const;
operator Dollars() const;

The above will result in "Error C2059 syntax error: 'newline'."

Comment: I cannot reproduce that result, the execution (in a single file) prints "20 dollars" and terminates without any error. Note also that these two lines aren't following each other in the real codes : the first is in the Cents class (where it replaces your initial definition) and the second in the Dollars class (idem). Is it what you did ?

Comment: I tried solving with your method but I just couldn't solve it. Thanks for the help.